# create a circular navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to create a circular menu with navigation items. Constraint is that text is also curved. Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFFpE/) for what I was through by drawing 2 canvases, but I am still not able to bind click on item cause of box model constraints. We can make later canvas transparent and place it over original div or render text while rendering canvas in top canvas.

[image]

Code-

```
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle, position, adjustFactor){
    context.save();
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);
    context.rotate((position-1)*45*Math.PI/180);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);
    context.rotate((adjustFactor-str.length)/(2*adjustFactor)*45*Math.PI/180);
    for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
        context.rotate(angle / str.length);
        context.save();
        context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
        var char = str[n];
        context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
        context.restore();
    }
    context.restore();
}
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var inputText = ["BIRTH","SCHOOL","JOB","COLLEGE","LIFE","MARRIAGE","OTHERS","OTHERS"];
    var adjustFactor = 10;
    context.font = "12pt Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "silver";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height - 200;
    //var angle = 45*Math.PI/180 // radians
    var angle = inputText.length/adjustFactor*45*Math.PI/180;
    var radius = 160;
    for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
        var position = i+1;
        var angle = inputText[i].length/adjustFactor*45*Math.PI/180
        //var adjustFactor=Math.round(inputText[i].length*3.33);
        console.log(adjustFactor);
        drawTextAlongArc(context, inputText[i], centerX, centerY, radius, angle, position,adjustFactor);
    }
    //var position = 4;    
};
```

Comment: I would like to say that you can implement this kind of circular menu using pure CSS without the need of canvas.

Comment: You need to add an EventListener for your canvas element. Something like:

>gCanvasElement.addEventListener("click", function_to_open_the_link, false)

Comment: Here some examples about event listeners for canvas elements.
[http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#halma](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#halma)