# canvas renders twice on android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, backbone.js, canvas

I am trying to draw a canvas in my mobile app built using Backbone but the issue is that canvas is getting rendered twice and sometimes distorted. Here is the fiddle. Need a fix for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/FFFpE/

```
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle, position, adjustFactor){
                        context.save();
                        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
                        context.rotate((position-1)*45*Math.PI/180);
                        context.rotate(-1 * (angle / str.length) / 2);
                        context.rotate((adjustFactor-str.length)/(2*adjustFactor)*45*Math.PI/180);
                        for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                            context.rotate(angle / str.length);
                            context.save();
                            context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
                            var char = str[n];
                            context.fillText(char, 0, 0);
                            context.restore();
                        }
                        context.restore();
                    }
```

Comment: what is context? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am making a circular navigation menu for mobile web app. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673749/create-a-circular-navigation-menu. I was able to do it and track clicks for dynamically created tags but canvas is not rendering properly or it renders twice.

Comment: your code seems to be too complex for such a simple thing, try to simplify it